# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function``` when using jcountdown via rails-assets-pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, countdowntimer

I'm having problems when it comes displaying the timer in my page when using jcountdown via the `rails-assets-pipeline`

> **Error message:** Uncaught TypeError: $(...).countdown is not a function

**Code:**

*countdown_timer.js*

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#timeleft").countdown({
    "date" : "november 07, 2015"
  });
});
```

*view:*

```
<div id="timeleft"></div>
```

I understand the error, but not knowing too much about javascript so I don't know how to fix it. I'm following the instructions as per their wiki page [jcountdown](https://github.com/tomgrohl/jCountdown)

I removed the `//= (*=)require jcountdown` from `application.js` and `application.scss` because `unable to find stylesheets using turboliks`

Comment: How are you loading in this jquery plugin?  if countdown is not defined the simplest explanation is an import problem.

Comment: via the rails-asset-pipeline. In my ```Gemfile:``` ```source 'https://rails-assets.org' do gem 'rails-assets-jcountdown' end```

Comment: are you also including jquery?

Comment: Well it's already included on every rails app when I prebuilt it ```'gem jquery-rails'``` or should I also include it in my ```rails-assets-pipeline``` as well?

Comment: Honestly not sure.  you could also try sticking two script tags linked to cdnjs for jquery and jquery.countdown.  https://cdnjs.com/ to narrow the problem down.

Comment: I added the following tags : 
```<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.countdown/2.1.0/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>```         
 ```<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-alpha1/jquery.min.js"></script>```
to my ```application.html.erb``` but I'm still getting the same error ```countdown is not define```

Comment: switch the order of those script tags

Comment: Just did now getting ```Uncaught Error: Couldn't cast `[object Object]` to a date object.```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that we've successfully gotten the library to load,

replace

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#timeleft").countdown({
      "date" : "november 07, 2015"
    });
});
```

with

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#timeleft").countdown("2015/11/07");
});
```

For more information, i'd refer to the most up to date version of the docs [here](http://hilios.github.io/jQuery.countdown/)

EDIT:

There is a simple example given as well on the page, though I will repeat it here.

html

```
<div id="getting-started"></div>
```

and js

```
$("#getting-started")
  .countdown("2016/01/01", function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
    );
 });
```

Comment: So tried what you recommended and even tried to put the string inside a variable and calling variable but keep getting the same error. Should I use a ```startTime``` and ```timeEnd parameter``` inside my countdown function?

code I have now:
```$(document).ready(function(){
  var startTime = 'november 07, 2015'
  $("#timeleft").countdown(startTime);
});```

Comment: might not be a supported date format, try another like in the docs - 2015/11/07

Comment: Hey, so I updated the code as you recommended, and when I do it on from the html page itself inside a ```<script type='text/javascript'></script>``` from the page itself it works, but then when I upload the same code inside a javascript file it doesn't work.  

I'll keep tinkering with it. Thanks man

Comment: @JonahWilliams i have a query..if days are 00 days how can we show just hours minutes and seconds only??

Answer (score 2):

I added

```
<script src="js/jquery.countdown.js"></script>
```

to last line of body and it worked. It was happening because this js was not getting loaded for my page.

Answer (score 0):

check all your script files you should store on server. if any is missing you would get the above error. that fixed mine.

```
<script src="[path]/jquery.countdown.min.js"></script>
```

visit the link `https://[path]/jquery.countdown.min.js` to make sure the file can be found